# Why aren't these threads working simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on this code, where I need to capture videos simultaneously using single PiCamera in opencv using Raspberry pi.. And a friend suggested to use threading(although I saw some people mentioning multithreading won't work in python??) and I don't know why, second video is captured after keyboard interrupt using 'q' as in programme..
Can anyone help me finding where the code is going wrong??
I want same camera to record multiple videos with 1 second delay between each.. 
Here's is the code

```
import cv2
import threading
import time

global tx
tx = []

def cap_1():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        out1 = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
        while(cap.isOpened()):
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if ret == True:
                        out1.write(frame)
                        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
                                break
                else:
                        break
        cap.release()
        out1.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def cap_2():
        cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        out2 = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
        while(cap2.isOpened()):
                ret, frame1 = cap2.read()
                if ret == True:
                        out2.write(frame1)
                        cv2.imshow('frame1',frame1)
                        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
                                break
                else:
                        break
        cap2.release()
        out2.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()



if __name__ == "__main__":
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=cap_1)
        tx.append(t1)
        print(tx)
        t1.start()
        t1.join()

        time.sleep(1)

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=cap_2)
        tx.append(t2)
        t2.start()
        t2.join()

        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: multithreading **does** work in python! it just won't help you speed up CPU intensive tasks. https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock . if `cv2` supports [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html?module-asyncio) you may want to look into that.

Comment: and: `t1.join()` waits for the first thread to finish. before you start the second one with `t2.start()`...

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.videoCapture(camIdx)` fetches the input directly from the camera in your device, and trying to split thread at that time won't yield you the result you are looking for as your threads will be sequentialized (in most systems, if not all) as they try to capture frames from the camera, however what you are trying to do can be achieved by using threads once you have read the frame, i.e. you can introduce the delay while writing to the file. i.e. use threads after `cap.read()` function.